# Product sigma algebra in the countable case

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega_i,\mathcal{F_i})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be the countable family of measurable spaces.Then I was wondering whether the canonical product sigma algebra on the product space that is for example defined via cylinder sets agrees with

$$\sigma(\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i;A_i\in  \mathcal{F}_i)?$$

This seems to be somehow a natural definition to define the sigma algebra on the product space, but is it what we canonically have in mind?-This certainly works for finite products, but what is in the countable case?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497667/product-sigma-algebra-in-countable-case-proposition-1-3-in-folland

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product $\sigma$-algebra in countable case (Proposition 1.3 in Folland)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497667/product-sigma-algebra-in-countable-case-proposition-1-3-in-folland)